# Как передать агрументы в shell script из ansible?

Tags: redis, shell

Добрый день.
 Хочу автоматизировать процесс развертывая redis (3.0.5) кластера, залип на установке сервиса, мне нужно для уставновки сервиса заранить sh скрипт, который просит аргументы ( tcp port, redis.conf location place и другое ).
 Пробовал через shell: и command: - вывод просто висит и ожидает ввода аргументов, sudo само собой есть.
 Посоветуйте как передать эти аргументы из ansible.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вы не правильно подходите к вопросу.

1. Суть Ansible как раз в том, чтоб отказаться по возможности от баш скриптов.
2. Не нужно писать велосипеды, когда уже есть готовые решения почти для всего.

В случае с Redis есть [ansible-redis](https://github.com/DavidWittman/ansible-redis).

Comment: Этот принцип я понимаю и  поддерживаю - ибо наслоение сущностей не есть правильный подход. Дело в том что я хотел redis 3 который пока что не присутствует в репах и собрать кластер на нем.
 На самом деле я не знаю что лучше использовать redis 3 cluster или с sentinel. Пока что новичок.

Comment: @dezzinto мы пишем онлайн игру и используем Redis для некоторых вещей. Кластер у Релиса слишком, хм, сырой и нестабильный. Мы решили использовать именно sentinel. Пока проблем с ним не было. Так что, советую попробовать именно sentinel.

Comment: @dezzinto btw, по той ссылке, что я привёл, редис же как раз из сорсов и собирается, а не из репы.

Comment: да - но там 2.8, хотя я писал что хотел бы 3

Comment: @dezzinto там в файлике https://github.com/DavidWittman/ansible-redis/blob/master/defaults/main.yml поменяйте версию и всё

Comment: Спасибо - а нет ли у вас минутки - чтобы описать как устроен ваш кластер  ? Есть ли шардинг - как вы добавляете ноды для масштабирования ? Я начал читать про чужой опыт и тут кто как делает - кто в докер пакует,  кто haproxy рулит.

Comment: @dezzinto шардинга нет. Ноды добавляем в конфиг и рестартим сентинель.

Comment: те одна нода - одна база ? и соответственно масштабирования нету ?

Comment: @dezzinto 3 ноды

Comment: ну а если база вырастает больше чем есть на инстансе ? что тогда делаете ?

Comment: @dezzinto у нас машины по 32+ гига памяти. Не думаю, что с этим проблемы будут. Если будут, будем шардить.

Comment: Ясно - тогда это не то что я искал - все таки мне нужен кластер

Comment: @dezzinto так в чём проблема? Если надо добавить новые машины, дописываете в конфиг. Хотя, сентинель вроде сам обновляет конфиг файл, когда новая машина появится в кластере.

Comment: в том что мне нужно хранить базу которая утром может быть 30 гиг и ей нужно 60 гиг места - и это действительно короткое время - 1 или 2 часа - которые нужно чтобы обработать эту дату. После чего размер падает до 4-5 гиг, с которыми потом работают дальше. И мой план был в том чтобы до начала роста базы автоматически добавлять новые инсты ( aws ) для шардинга этих 30 гиг после чего сжимать кластер до маленького состояния.

Comment: и все делать в aws.

Comment: @dezzinto я с aws не работал никогда =/

Comment: ну собственно это как раз задача для ansible\chef и подобного - чтобы делать независимый IS as code.

Comment: и из всего этого стоит вопрос - стоит ли вообще этим заморачиваться или нет. также есть вопрос - как писать и читать в кластер ? - поднимать прокси ? - четкого ответа нету и я думал что у вас похожая схема и есть опыт.

Comment: @dezzinto с Редисом всё сложно в этом плане. Что не встречал, там люди всегда много поверх него делали. У нас там просто токены хранятся, даже если мы потеряем все эти данные, нам это не критично.